# sscanf() double & string

Tags: c

I am fairly new to the world of programming so please forgive me if this is a common mistake.

I'm trying to scan 3 double values and 3 strings out of one input string but it doesnt continue after the second value.

```
double total_weight_kg(char *s, int Length) {
    double weights[3];
    char units[3];
    int test = sscanf(s, "%lf, %s, %lf, %s, %lf, %s",
                      &weights[0], &units[0],
                      &weights[1], &units[1],
                      &weights[2], &units[2]);
    printf("%i\n", test);
    printf("%s\n", &units[0]);

int main(void) {
    total_weight_kg("5, g, 1, t, 175, kg", 3);
    return 0;
```

The first print prints out 2 and the second the g.

Furthermore I'd like to compare units[i] in a loop but can't seem to get that working either.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++) {
    w = weights[i];
    if (strcmp(units[i], "kg") == 0) {
        weight += w;
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me find a solution for this problem,

edit: Everyting is working as intended now. Thank you very much for your help. ( 19[^,] was one major problem )

Comment: The `scanf` format `"%s"` is for reading null-terminated strings. Your array `units` is an array of three single `char` elements, not strings. The compiler should have been shouting warnings at you (both for that and for the `strcmp` call).

Comment: `char units[3];` won't hold g and kg. you've got buffer overflow here. You have to create a char[] array like `char units[3][10]` for instance.

Comment: We forgive you: C strings are hell.

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems in your code:

- To scan the strings into `units`, you must define it as a 2D array of `char`:

  ```
  char units[3][20];
  ```
- You should modify the `scanf` format to stop the word parsing on `,` and spaces, as suggested by user3386109.
- Also modify the `printf` to pass the array instead of its address.

Here is the modified code:

```
double total_weight_kg(char *s, int Length) {
    double weights[3];
    char units[3][20];
    int test = sscanf(s, "%lf, %19[^, \n], %lf, %19[^, \n], %lf, %19[^, \n]",
                      &weights[0], units[0],
                      &weights[1], units[1],
                      &weights[2], units[2]);
    printf("%i\n", test);
    printf("%s\n", units[0]);
   ...
}

int main(void) {
    total_weight_kg("5, g, 1, t, 175, kg", 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I changed it to char units[3][20]; but if I tr to compile the code it just tells me "%s expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 4 has type 'char (*)[20]" What do I have to do to change that?

Comment: @mejasper: post the code for the whole function and whatever is necessary for a minimal compilable example.

Comment: @mejasper: Also remove the extraneous `&` from the `units[0]` arguments to `scanf()`.

Comment: There's the additional problem that `%s` won't stop when it sees the comma, so the conversion needs to be `%19[^,],`